# 64 bit AR plugin for Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, 64-bit, augmented-reality

we have a unity project (for iOS and Android) in which AR is to be implemented. I had used Vuforia in past. However, it has come to my knowledge that Vuforia and in2ar do not have 64-bit support.

Both of them give this (or similar) error for their respective DLLs - "....dll', expected 64-bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386."

Also, Vuforia has issues with Unity 5's Canvas UI.

Also thought of using Metaio SDK, however, it seems they have stopped support and there is no way to download the SDK without emailing them.

So, can anyone assist me in knowing which AR Unity plugin can be used which has 64-bit support (as apple requires a 64-bit build from now on) and works with Unity 5's Canvas UI?

Comment: Vuforia 4 supports 64 bit architecture. They have issues with uGUI in 5.1.0 so you have to stay with Unity 5.0.3f until they play together well again

Comment: @Kay, thanks for the reply. I am using Unity 5.0.0f4 and when I drag ARCamera into my scene unity says - " Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386."
Also somewhere either on stackoverflow or on unity forum it was suggested to download Unity 32 bit but I think it cannot make a 64 bit iOS build (or can it?)

Also on Vuforia's site in their release notes they have mentioned - "Canvas UI element with the 4.2.3 ARCamera will not render the UI element on iOS and will show a white screen on Android"

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Vuforia, and have also followed the upgrade steps detailed on their forum https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/iOS-64-Bit-Migration

Comment: 5.0.0 is pretty old. I use 5.0.3f2 because I ran into this UI bug in 5.1 but it might be solved with 5.1.1. AMD 64? This sounds strange, AFAIK there are no AMDs inside of a Mac. I had some issues resolved by the Vuforia forum moderators. Maybe you should post this over there.

Comment: @Dover8 I will surely try what you have said and will revert.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia 4.2.3 for Unity 5.0.0f4 64 bit worked for me. I just ignored the error and deployed the app on an android device and it read marker and showed an object.

All fine, however do we have a way around to use Unity's canvas UI with Vuforia?

or

Do we have any other AR plugin for Unity 5 64 bit which supports Unity Canvas UI?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey guys happen to fix this issue too. Followed answer of this post - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/952783/any-stable-ar-image-tracking-plugin-for-unity-5.html